# OSX Loading dylib Lua Module

Tags: macos, lua, dylib, shared-libraries

When trying to load a Lua module on OSX I receive the following error.

```
lua: level1.lua:1: module 'libexpand_luaLib' not found:
    no field package.preload['libexpand_luaLib']
    no file './libexpand_luaLib.lua'
    no file '/opt/local/share/lua/5.1/libexpand_luaLib.lua'
    no file '/opt/local/share/lua/5.1/libexpand_luaLib/init.lua'
    no file '/opt/local/lib/lua/5.1/libexpand_luaLib.lua'
    no file '/opt/local/lib/lua/5.1/libexpand_luaLib/init.lua'
    no file './libexpand_luaLib.so'
    no file '/opt/local/lib/lua/5.1/libexpand_luaLib.so'
    no file '/opt/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    level1.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

The lua interpreter is trying to load a .so file and not a .dylib file. I was under the impression that .dylib is the OSX equivalent(with slight changes) of .so. So I'd expect the Lua interpreter to be looking for a .dylib file.

Should I be trying to compile my library into a .so on OSX?(If so how?) Or should I be changing something related to the lua interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to change the interpreter (provided that the .dynlib is loadable (as per [Programming in Lua, chapter 26](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.html) )).
You can change the package.cpath to look for .dynlibs instead of .so's, before requiring the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";?.dylib"
print(package.cpath)
rtn = require ("libme")
print(rtn)
```

Works just fine on osx.